# frozen computer after messing with grub

Tags: grub

I have messed up: I have an asus laptop, just installed 18.04, and might have changed a line in /etc/default/grub by mistake.

Now when I turn the laptop on, I can get to the login, but just get a blank screen afterwards. If I press ctrl+alt+F1 I get a scrolling list of "PCIe Bus error severity=Corrected", and cannot do anything after that.

I have tried to restore the grub file via a USB live version, but after a few minutes the computer freezes, and even if I manage to get to the file, it tells me there is no space left, and that I cannot modify it.

I have loads of important documents on this device, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The error you mention most likely has nothing to do with `GRUB`, it happens much too later, after the system is already booted.

The error messages may filled up the disk, you can look in `/var/log` for large files and delete what you think you don't need.

You have already booted with a USB live system, just use that system to copy your documents, either to USB storage or to a server on the network.

Comment: the problem is that the disk gets filled quite fast, after a couple of minutes the live system just freezes, so I have no time to copy/delete files.

Comment: If your life system freezes, that confirms my suspicion that it is a hardware problem and has nothing to do with GRUB. You could kill syslog or whatever writes to your log files, but normally a system won't freeze because the disk is full. I would attach the disk to a different system and copy the files there. If you want to avoid that, try booting with the command line option `1` or `single` in the GRUB menu.

Comment: ok! but how can I modify these options if I have no access to the GRUB menu? (sorry, I'm really new to all this!)

Comment: GRUB is often used with a graphical interface. In this you can just type your options. If you don't have a graphical interface, or if you press ESC to leave it, in the text interface your can press 'e' for edit.